# How to handle d.elementFromPoint is not a function?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm using c# SeleniumWebdriver (chromedriver 2.38.*) and running into an error of the sort

```
unknown error: d.elementFromPoint is not a function
```

It happens when I do a call like this

```
Actions a = new Actions(Driver);
a.DoubleClick(theElement).Perform();
```

Respectively theElement.Location, theElement.Displayed, theElement.Enabled are not null, true, true.

I read stackOverflow a bit, and so to try to resolve this I called

```
js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver;                            
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", theElement);
```

but it didn't help! There is some shadow root stuff going on in the page, I don't know if that changes anything or not. What do people suggest to fix this general issue?

Comment: Update the chromedriver and the browser.

Comment: 2.38 is the latest version compatible with the framework I am executing in.

Comment: I see. 2.38 is quiet an old version, about an year old. This is almost certainly the cause. Is there no possibility to update Chrome on this framework (I assume that's why you can't update the chromedriver ?).

Comment: No I am stuck with 2.38 i'm actually working in electron and not a web browser